# LBP 2900 printer error

Tags: drivers, usb, printing

I hope some one can help.

I have been using my LBP2900 printer on Ubuntu 14.04 for 2 years without major problems, but recently after some updates it stopped working. I'm unsure what updates it was as I did not pay much attention to it.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the printer and followed all the guides I could find.

But the problem is still the same, it says "communication error".. and I have no idea what to do..

`captstatusui -P LBP2900`
says `communication error`

`sudo ccpdadmin`
says:

```
CUPS_ConfigPath = /etc/cups/
LOG Path = None
UI Port = 59787


Entry Num : Spooler : Backend : FIFO path : Device Path : Status 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0] : LBP2900 : ccp : //localhost:59787 : /dev/usb/lp0 :
```

`lsusb`
says:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0b05:7782 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04a9:2676 Canon, Inc. CAPT Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1908:2310 GEMBIRD 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2d23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`/usr/sbin/lpinfo -v`
says

```
network ipps
network ipp
direct usb://Canon/LBP2900?serial=0000D2D6SIQU
network lpd
network socket
network ipp14
direct ccp
network https
network http
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
serial serial:/dev/ttyS4?baud=115200
direct hp
network smb
direct hpfax
```

`service ccpd status`
says

```
Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS: ccpd: 20029 20025
```

I hope someone can help me to get this fixed....

Comment: Can any one help?